# How accurate is the W3C Geolocation API?

Tags: html, geolocation, w3c-geolocation

I have been reading the [W3C Geolocation API specification](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) and I was wondering if anyone has found any information on how accurate the location returned is.

I found the `accuracy` attribute:

> The accuracy attribute denotes the accuracy level of the latitude and
>   longitude coordinates. It is specified in meters and must be supported
>   by all implementations. The value of the accuracy attribute must be a
>   non-negative real number.

But I'm wondering if anyone is aware of a possible range for these values?  Is there a maximum number of meters that will be returned?

Any application I wrote that used this would be used in a relatively small geographic area, does the accuracy depend on where that area is?

**Note:**

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242462/exactly-how-accurate-is-ip-geolocation), but it does not talk about the accuracy range and I believe they are talking about using Google's GeoLocation service.

Comment: The accuracy depends on the hardware and local radio conditions, not the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on experience the accuracy on device without GPS, like laptop that only relies on Wifi mapping, is 100-200 meters in urbanized area. With GPS, like in mobile phone browser its as goods as it gets, 10-30 meters.