# Obtain a client's location coordinates through the browser's geolocation API, or resolve through IP address from the server?

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, geolocation, geodjango

I'm wondering which method to go with for fairly accurate locationing, + scalability and speed.

It seems Django's Geoip has a limited number of addresses. And IPs are some times redirected to the ISP generated address. 
The advantage of using GeoIP would be that I don't have to fiddle around client-side. Would using IP, and relying on Maxmind be a practical hinderance?

On the other hand, using the browser's Geolocation API, I believe I can obtain a much more accurate location, but only if it's first "Allow[ed]" by the client. It would then involve sending the coordinates to the backend for further processing using something like Geodjango to resolve the coordinates.

What am I missing? Can someone shed some light on the differences? Does it not matter much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All depends on how accurate you need your application to be.

- If you don't care about accuracy, use GeoIP (described as [hit-or-miss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242462/exactly-how-accurate-is-ip-geolocation?rq=1))
- If you care about accuracy, go with the Geolocation API option.

So for your specific case, go with the second option.